# Can't publish to IIS - Copying file failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2013

> Error 5   Copying file Uploads\People\bzbu0pdh.png to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Uploads\People\bzbu0pdh.png failed. Could not find file 'Uploads\People\bzbu0pdh.png'.       0   0   SampleProject.Web

I get this error when I try to publish my project from Visual Studio 2013. I'm pretty sure this is an unwanted file. 
I tried creating a file with the same name and putting it in Uploads\People and included that in project. It didn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

Browse to that directory in Visual Studio and you'll see that VS believes there to be a file there. you can right click and exclude it from the project and VS will update the project file for you.